# Check if any element has 0 height

Tags: jquery, css, function, height

I've got a group of elements:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

and a function

```
function heightCheck(){
  $('ul li').each(function(){
    if($(this).height == 0){
      heightCheck();
    }else{
      nextFunction();
    }
  })
}
```

Basically I want it to keep checking the "li" elements for height until all elements are greater than 0 height. As it is right now, it'll fire nextFunction if the first element is ok but the rest aren't. I need all the elements to have height before going forward.

Comment: You are ending up as recursion if the elements `height` is 0...

Comment: What will cause the height of the li to change?

Comment: height of `li` will not `0` even if it's empty

Comment: @TusharGupta why is that so? http://jsfiddle.net/MuXC5/

Comment: @Musa There are things being loaded in, images, videos or anything.

Comment: @MattCoady console says too much recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than call the function recursively, you should use an interval.  It seems like you are waiting for some asynchronous calls to fill up the list items.  You can either check when all of these are done (probably the better option) or use an interval to check:

```
var heightInterval;
function nextFunction () {
    clearInterval(heightInterval);
    // etc.
}
heightInterval = setInterval(function () {
    var done = true;
    $('ul li').each(function(){
        if($(this).height() == 0){
            done = false;
            return false;
        }
    })
    if (done) {
        nextFunction();
    }
// check each second
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
function heightCheck(){
  var heightError = 0;
  $('ul li').each(function(){
    if($(this).height == 0){
      heightError = 1;
      heightCheck();
    }
  });

  if(heightError == 0){
    nextFunction();
  }
}
```

I used the var `heightError` to verify

Answer (score 0):

I believe that whatever

```
function heightCheck(){
  var checkHeight = false;
  for(var i =0; i > elements.height; i++){
     checkHeight = checkHeight ||(elements.eq(i).height == 0);

     if(checkHeight) break;   
  }
  if(checkHeight)
     heightCheck();
   }else{
     nextFunction();
   }
 }
```